# <br> dont make new line

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
.pt_t {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.pt_p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="pt_p">1. Line</span>
<br>
<span class="pt_t">2. Line</span>
<br>
<span class="pt_t">3. Line</span>
<span class="pt_t">is</span>
<span class="pt_t">here</span>
```

The first span and the second span should be in two lines, the third, fourth and fifth span in the same line.

Why my code dont work?

Comment: "*I want each span to be on a separate line*" - "*because some spans need to be in same line*" quite contradictory no?

Comment: Do you want it to be three lines of text all aligned at the left or something else? `<br>` is doing what it should be doing, it's probably just not what you expect. If you remove it, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Use a `p` or `h1` for thing on different lines. Use a `span` for things needed on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple remove float : left; Like  :

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.pt_t {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.pt_p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <span class="pt_p">Hello!</span>
  <br>
  <span class="pt_t">Some text</span>
  <br>
  <span class="pt_t">Lorem ispum</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting `float: left;` on each span you are basically bypassing `<br>`. With float, the element is removed from the normal flow of the page and placed on the left/right side of its container (`body` in this case), allowing other text to wrap around it.

Just remove it:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.pt_t {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.pt_p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <span class="pt_p">Hello!</span>
  <br>
  <span class="pt_t">Some text</span>
  <br>
  <span class="pt_t">Lorem ispum</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bad solution, if you really need `float: left;`, is just to add `clear: both;` to br:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
.pt_t {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.pt_p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
br {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<span class="pt_p">Hello!</span>
<br>
<span class="pt_t">Some text</span>
<br>
<span class="pt_t">Lorem ispum</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need `float: left` use `display: grid`:

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.pt_div{
  display: grid;
}

.pt_t {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    float: left;

}

.pt_p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
    float: left;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="pt_div">
      <span class="pt_p">1. Line</span>
      <span class="pt_t">2. Line</span>
      <span class="pt_t">3. Line is here</span>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<br>` tag works if you write in one tag only
For example

```html
<span class="pt_p">Hello! <br>
  Some text</span>
```

Also you can set `display:flex` `flex-flow:column` to the parent (body) to show it as column

```css
body {
  background-color: #202020;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}


.parent1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <span>1 text</span>
  <span>2 text</span>
  <span>3 text</span>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <span>
    1 text <br>
    2 text<br>
    3 text<br>
  </span>
</div>
```